# Why *this=door is correct?

Tags: c++

```
Door::Door(const Door& door)
{
    *this = door;
}
```

I am very confused with this copy constructor. For me, it does not make sense to use `*this=door`, but rather

```
Door::Door(const Door& door)
{
    this->color = door.color;
    this->destination = door.destination;
}
```

Can you explain why `*this=door` is correct?

**EDIT**

As it is suggested, I need to overload `=` for the class. So I got something like

```
const Porte& operator =(const Porte& source)
{
    this->color = door.color;
    this->destination = door.destination;
}
```

So I am right to use `*this=door` now. Why isn't it rather `this=door` instead?

Comment: Well, what's the implementation of `Door::operator=(const Door&)`? It's likely to be doing the same thing. And if I were to change it I probably wouldn't use either version but rather one using member initializer lists.

Comment: `this.color` is not valid C++

Comment: Note that this can get you into trouble since you usually build your `operator=()` thinking that `*this` will be in a good state, which it may not be if it hasn't been constructed yet. (ie: if you're keeping pointers and `operator=()` tries to `delete` them before newly allocating on the assumption there was already something allocated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It invokes `Door::operator=(Door const &other)`.

If that operator is explicitly implemented, it does whatever the implementation says it does. If it's implicitly generated, it simply copies the values of all members.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a prvalue **pointer**. Pointers do not have members and correspondingly you cannot apply the member access operator on a pointer.

> ```
>    this.color = door.color;
>    this.destination = door.destination;
> ```

To access the pointed object through a pointer, you must indirect through the pointer using an indirection operator. In the first program, the unary * is used which is the indirection operator.

There is also a member access indirection operator -> which is a shorthand for indirecting through a pointer and accessing member of the pointed object. As such, you could write:

```
this->color = door.color;
this->destination = door.destination;
```

The first example instead uses the assignment operator to do the same thing.

Neither of these is something that I would recommend. Best way to implement a copy constructor is in order of preference. If the first one is not applicable, then use the next and so on:

- If you don't need to, don't declare copy constructor at all and use the implicitly generated one.
- Define the constructor as explicitly defaulted (or deleted).
- Initialise the members and leave the constructor body empty.

> why it is not this=door instead?

Because it is not supposed to assign the pointer. It is supposed to assign the pointed object. As I explained above, you must indirect through the pointer (using indirection operator) in order to access the pointed object.

Besides, `this` is an rvalue, so it cannot be assigned.

Comment: I have modify my question. Can you just explain roughly why it is not `this=door` instead? Why can't we access the member of an object through a pointer?